# Are 'const foo**' and 'foo** const' the same thing?

Tags: c++

I know that for a type `foo`, the function declaration for `bar`

```
void bar(const foo*) and void bar(foo* const)
```

are the same thing. But that about double indirection? That is, are

```
void bar(const foo**) and void bar(foo** const)
```

also the same thing? If not, then what do I need to do to `void bar(foo** const)` to put the `const` first?

Comment: In the second case, they are different. `const foo**` is a pointer to a pointer to a const `foo` while `foo** const` is a const pointer to a pointer to a nonconst `foo`. OTOH `const foo*` is a pointer to a const `foo` while `foo* const` is a const pointer to a nonconst `foo`.

Comment: @AnoopRana: Sorry but I had a typo in the first one.

Comment: `const foo *` is the same as `foo const *`, but neither is the same as `foo * const`.

Comment: C++ FAQ [Why am I getting an error converting a Foo** → const Foo**?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#constptrptr-conversion)

Comment: These *declarations* are the same thing: `void bar(foo*);` and `void bar(foo* const);`  The `const` doesn't affect the signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Case 1

Here we consider

```
void bar(const foo*); #1
void bar(foo* const)  #2
```

In `#1` we've a *pointer to a `const foo`* while in `#2` we've a *const pointer to a nonconst `foo`*.

You could use `std::is_same` to confirm that they're different:

```
std::cout << std::is_same<const foo*, foo* const>::value << ' ';   //false
```

##### Case 2

Here we consider

```
void bar(const foo**); #3
void bar(foo** const); #4
```

In `#3` we've a *pointer to a pointer to a `const foo`* while in `#4` we've a *const pointer to a nonconst pointer to a nonconst `foo`*.

```
std::cout << std::is_same<const foo**, foo** const>::value << ' '; //false
```

---

Moreover, note that `const foo *` is the same as `foo const *` but this case you don't have in your given examples.

```
std::cout << std::is_same<const foo *, foo const *>::value << ' '; //true
```